# How to use Python scrapy for myltiple URL's

Tags: scrapy, python-3.5

my question is similar to this post:

[How to use scrapy for Amazon.com links after "Next" Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455961/how-to-use-scrapy-for-amazon-com-links-after-next-button)

I want my crawler to traverse through all "Next" links. I've searched a lot, but most people ether focus on how to parse the ULR or simply put all URL's in the initial URL list.

So far, I am able to visit the first page and parse the next page's link. But I don't know how to visit that page using the same crawler(spider). I tried to append the new URL into my URL list, it does appended (I checked the length), but later it doesn't visit the link. I have no idea why...

Note that in my case, I only know the first page's URL. Second page's URL can only be obtained after visiting the first page. The same, (i+1)'th page's URL is hidden in the i'th page.

In the parse function, I can parse and print the correct next page link URL. I just don't know how to visit it.

Please help me. Thank you!

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test2"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.reddit.com"]
    urls = ["https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/search?q=timestamp%3A1427232122..1437773560&sort=new&restrict_sr=on&syntax=cloudsearch"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                'endpoint': 'render.html',
                'args': { 'wait': 0.5 }
                }
            })
`

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url[-10:]
        print(page)
        filename = 'reddit-%s.html' % page
        #parse html for next link
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
        mydivs = soup.findAll("a", { "rel" : "nofollow next" })
        link = mydivs[0]['href']
        print(link)
        self.urls.append(link)

        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

#### Update

Thanks to Kaushik's answer, I figured out how to make it work. Though I still don't know why my original idea of appending new URL's doesn't work...
The updated code is as follow:

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test2"
    urls = ["https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/search?q=timestamp%3A1427232122..1437773560&sort=new&restrict_sr=on&syntax=cloudsearch"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                'endpoint': 'render.html',
                'args': { 'wait': 0.5 }
                }
            })


    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url[-10:]
        print(page)
        filename = 'reddit-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        #parse html for next link
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')
        mydivs = soup.findAll("a", { "rel" : "nofollow next" })
        if len(mydivs) != 0:
            link = mydivs[0]['href']
            print(link)  
            #yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you require is explained very well in the [Scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) . I don't think you would need any other explanation other than that. Suggest going through it once for better understanding.

---

A brief explanation first though:

To follow a link to the next page, Scrapy provides many methods. The most basic methods is using the [http.Request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) method

> [Request object](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) :
>   class scrapy.http.Request(url[, callback,
>   method='GET', headers, body, cookies, meta, encoding='utf-8',
>   priority=0, dont_filter=False, errback, flags])

```
>>> yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.next_parse)
```

- url (string) – the URL of this request
- callback (callable) – the function that will be called with the response of this request (once its downloaded) as its first parameter.

---

For convenience though, Scrapy has inbuilt shortcut for creating Request objects by using [response.follow](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.follow) where the url can be an absolute path or a relative path.

> follow(url, callback=None, method='GET', headers=None, body=None,
>   cookies=None, meta=None, encoding=None, priority=0, dont_filter=False,
>   errback=None)

```
>>> yield response.follow(url, callback=self.next_parse)
```

---

In case if you have to move through to the next link by passing values to a **form** or any other type of **input** field, you can use the [Form Request objects](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html?highlight=form#formrequest-objects). The [FormRequest class](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html?highlight=form#scrapy.http.FormRequest) extends the base Request with functionality
 for dealing with HTML forms. It uses lxml.html forms to pre-populate
 form fields with form data from Response objects.

> [Form Request object](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/request-response.html?highlight=form#formrequest-objects)
>   from_response(response[, formname=None,
>   formid=None, formnumber=0, formdata=None, formxpath=None,
>   formcss=None, clickdata=None, dont_click=False, ...])

If you want to simulate a HTML Form **POST** in your spider and send a couple of key-value fields, you can return a FormRequest object (from your spider) like this:

```
return [FormRequest(url="http://www.example.com/post/action",
                    formdata={'name': 'John Doe', 'age': '27'},
                    callback=self.after_post)]
```

---

> Note : If a Request doesn’t specify a callback, the spider’s parse() method will be used. If exceptions are raised during processing, errback is called instead.

Comment: Thanks. It helps!

Comment: Sure, glad to help! If it is the what you were looking for, pls mark it as the answer.